# Drag and Drop GridView event not firing ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I had to implement ordering in the Grid View, I am using ASP.NET 4.0 currently. While searching I found the following [Utility](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21984/Drag-and-drop-GridView-items-for-ordering-in-ASP-N) at codeproject which helps to implement it. I cannot fire the DragAndDrop event. I have added the reference and also in the ASP.NET page using `using Utility;`. Below is my code:

**IN ASPX PAGE**

```
<cc1:DragDropGridView ID="_GridDragAndDrop" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ValGridForm" OnDragAndDrop="_GridDragAndDrop_DragAndDrop" >
            <Columns>
               .
               .
               .
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="label" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No record Found.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
</cc1:DragDropGridView>
```

**IN CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void _GridDragAndDrop_DragAndDrop(object sender, Utility.DragAndDropEventArgs e)
    { //Added a breakpoint here. But it does not hit here.

    }
```

**Problem**
Drag And Drop event is not hit when I drag a row, and release it somewhere down. The page loads, which means it does makes a PostBack, but is not hitting the event it should hit. I do not know where I am doing the problem.

Comment: Actually you do not provide any real informations about your problem. What is the error you get ? Everything work fines ? probably not, but what is not working ? You get a ready to run tutorial, and not run to you ? what you change and not run ? what javascript errors do you get ?

Comment: No errors are reported on the page, neither the Javascript based errors, nor any debug errors. I had two buttons which had two JQuery functions bind to them, when I click them they run but as soon as postback occurs the functions is reloaded and so it does not finish its task.